# How to calculate string font width in pixels?

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate string font width in pixels in **android**. I am having string array and I am appending all these array elements to form one string. so I have to set fixed spacing in between two consecutive array element.i am placing this final string into textview. Finally I am adding this textview to tablerow. In short i want to view table structure with title and values.  I have seen many post over here but not getting solution for this.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: While it does look like `measureText` is what you're specifically asking for, are you sure you need to make it this complicated? is there a reason why you can't use multiple TextViews perhaps laid out in a `TableLayout` instead?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like there is a `measureText` method available on [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29). I also found an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/MeasureText.html):

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setTextSize(64);
mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.ITALIC));
// ...
float w = mPaint.measureText(text, 0, text.length());
```

Answer (score 5):

[Thanks Jake for the working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360171/3508719), yet I found this to work for me too:

```
someText = "Lorem Ipsum";
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
float w = myTextView.getPaint().measureText(someText);
```

Getting the Paint directly from the TextView that I'm going to work with makes me feel that the anwser will be more accurate.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know if this works, but it can.

```
int textSize=20;
Paint p=new Paint();
p.setTextSize(textSize);
String string="Hello im a string.";
public int getStringWidt()
{
    return string.length*textSize;
}
```

Comment: Since the letters of fonts nowadays have different widths this is only an approximate solution (given the assumption textSize = letter size in pixels is correct)