# How to have a circular TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have been trying to make a circular `TextView`. Its a circle in which I want to accomodate whole space above a circular bubble as shown in image below.

Kindly see attached image.

[image: Circular bubble with text in side]

In this image, we have a circular bubble with circular text in it.
I have already tried setting oval shape `.xml` as background of `TextView` but still no luck.

Edit:

As text length increase. It must reduces in size to fit inside the circle. This is the hardest part to think about.

Answer (score 10):

You need to create a **custom view**, extending from `TextView` probably, setting the circle as background image, and calculate the text width / break the lines manually according to the width of the text.

To calculate the width of a string, see [How to calculate string font width in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360089/how-to-calculate-string-font-width-in-pixels)

Some math and calculations is required of course to measure the available space per line; but I think that's the only way, as there's no standard component out there to do it.

To place the text onto the view, use `drawText` of the [`Canvas` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Comment: +1, there's no built-in component for this. Also, creating custom views is fun :)

Comment: You said, "calculate the text width / break the lines manually according to the width of the text."

This needs to be dynamic to fit inside text of varying length inside the circle. How could I measure number of lines that my text will fills inside circle?

Comment: I think you would measure the entire text as one string, that gives you the entire needed width in px. Then you need to calculate the px space per line, starting from the center to the outside. I don't have a formula for that at hand, but that's probably the way I would start looking into it. Adding line breaks and then counting how many line breaks you needed. Of course this is kind of a 'dynamic' calculation, as the number of lines are directly related with the string length of each line. I'm sure it's a bit complicated and not that easy, but can be done ;-)