# How can I get the actual text size in px(not textSize attribute)?

Tags: android, unicode, textview, char, android-edittext

My question is not about the number of chars nor the textSize attribute in TextView/EditText.

I have a fixed EditText. And the maxLength is 10. And all the chars must be shown at once.
However, each char has different width and height. For example, l and L. If you drag the mouse over(block selection) the l and then the L. You will notice that they have different width.

So, LLLLLLLLLL and llllllllll has different width.

For instance,

LLLLLLLLLL

llllllllll

(both are 10 letters)

Moreover, different font shows different width.

My question is how to get the actual width of chars in PX so that the string won't hidden in the EditText. Let's say, the width of EditText is 200px. And it's limited to 10 letters. And it will show

LLLL(LLLLLL) // (LLLLL) is not shown because of the EditText's width. But you can see when you move the cursor.

llllllllll

How can you get the width of the chars?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360089/how-to-calculate-string-font-width-in-pixels/30446814

Comment: Hmm. So, I need to draw it with Paint and then get the width...?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TextPaint` and measure letters, but there is an easier way for your case. get familiar with [em unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29)

you can declare this value for `EditText`/`TextView` by `setEms(intNum)` or `android:ems="intNum"`. set also width to `wrap_content` and your `View` will have width of `intNum` widest characters (usually `M`s). there are also useful `minEms` and `maxEms` attributes

edit: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053738/what-is-meant-by-ems-android-textview) you have more complex explanation

PS. don't declare sizes of your `View`s with `px` unit due to different densities, use `dp`. some units explanation in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)